# Debug gets an ElasticSearch response while running normally does not

Tags: java, spring, debugging, elasticsearch

Hello I am new to ElasticSearch, but I ran into this interesting bug. If I run my project in debug mode, my SearchResponse returns my query. However, if I run it normally, it doesn't. Is there a reason why that happens?

I am using ElasticSearch 1.4.2, and using Java API, transport client.

My debug message is as shows when in debug mode:

```
DEBUG | Client Established
DEBUG | db created
DEBUG | Trying to get a response...
DEBUG | Response 1: org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse@1aa93fb
DEBUG | Search Response: {
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "db",
      "_type" : "user",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"user":"matt","content":"trying out Elasticsearch"}
    }, {
      "_index" : "db",
      "_type" : "user",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"user":"jim","content":"trying out Elasticsearch"}
    } ]
  }
}
```

My debug message is as shows when normal running:

```
DEBUG | Client Established
DEBUG | db created
DEBUG | Trying to get a response...
DEBUG | Response 1: org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse@d05471
DEBUG | Search Response: {  "took" : 1, 
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
DEBUG | elasticsearch response: 0 hits
```

Is running it normally not giving elasticsearch enough time to search for what it needs?

The query was:

```
    SearchResponse allHits1 = client.prepareSearch("costamesadb").setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()).execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: I am not able to come to any conclusion without seeing what queries were executed.

Comment: @VineethMohan I added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your application is creating the data and then searching for the created data soon after. Newly created data are not immediately visible for searches.

see [Near Real time search](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html)

You can use the GET API which is realtime, see [GET API](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#realtime)